# fopen("php://input", "r") returns 0

Tags: php, fopen, mamp

I have the line

```
$input = fopen( "php://input", "r" );
```

in a php script and I can't figure out why it is returning 0.  It is only doing so on my local MAMP set up.  I think it is a permission issue but I am not sure what permissions I need to modify.

Comment: How do you determine the return value is "0"? Is error reporting on/have you checked the log files for errors?

Comment: It sets the variable $input to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in some server for security reason **allow_url_fopen** set 0
in php.ini . search for this string **allow_url_fopen** and set it to  1 and restart apache service